# Issues Updating Post Meta with AJAX (Seems simple but cannot figure it out)

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, ajax, post-meta

First and foremost - thank you to anyone and everyone who is taking the time to respond. I am a newer developer and I am sure I have a misunderstanding or something simple that I am missing. I have spent hours trying different things and I am just not sure what to try now. Below you can find my code and an explanation of my problem.

What I am trying to achieve: Essentially I am trying to create a plugin to just edit all the meta descriptions on my pages from a plugin admin page.

With that in mind - I have created a very simple file with all the principals I am trying to achieve. The idea being that once I get this portion figured out, I will then figure out the proper loops to try and achieve my end goal. So below is the code as close to exact as I can get. Again, any help would be greatly appreciated - I have been testing for a while now and just cannot get this dang thing to work.

I have gotten the AJAX request to log that it was successful so I am totally lost because it doesn't save or update the database upon refresh.

```
    <?php
function ews_metas_add_admin_page() {
    // Adds plugin page to menu
    add_menu_page ('Effective Web Solutions Metas Descriptions', 'EWS Metas', 'manage_options', 'ews_meta_options_stephen_version', 'ews_meta_page_creation_stephen', get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/admin-ico-gray.png', 110 );
    //Activate custom settings
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'display_metas_fields');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ews_metas_add_admin_page'); ?>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".toplevel_page_ews_meta_options_stephen_version form").submit(function() {
            var post_meta = jQuery("input.testing").val();
            var post_ID = jQuery("input.testing").attr("name");
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'https://dev.ewsproduction.com/dev6/ewstheme/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                data: {
                    action: "update_meta_descriptions",
                    post_id: post_ID,
                    post_meta: post_meta,
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                //do something
                console.log('It worked!');
            }
        });
        return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<?php 
function ews_meta_page_creation_stephen() { ?>
<div>
    <?php settings_errors(); ?>
    <form method="post">
        <input id="meta" class="testing" type="text" name="4189" value="<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( 4189, '_metadescs', true ) ); ?>" />
        <?php submit_button();?>
    </form>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<?php add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_meta_descriptions', 'update_meta_descriptions' );
    function update_meta_descriptions() {
        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
        $meta = $_POST['post_meta'];
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_metadescs', $post_meta );
        echo 'Meta Updated';
    die();
```

}
    ?>

With all of that in mind - any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried just about everything I can find and no luck.

Any insight on my overall goal is also apprecaite - what I am trying to do is eventually create a plugin that lists all the Meta and Page Title information from each page on a plugin page. Then I would like to be able to edit and update those values from said plugin page.

Comment: Thank you @Anujayweb! Your help totally solved it and things are now working. Thanks for your time and explanation - it was super helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You did some mistakes that I have described below:*

- First thing you have placed jQuery Ajax code on the wrong place.
- On ajax callback function variable name mashup like $post_id defined and used on update time  $post_ID; PHP is case sensitive so it considers 2 different variables.
- In some places, not closed } brackets.

**Here is the right code which I have modified in your code.
Check this and let me know it's work for you or not.
I have tested it works for me.**

```
<?php /*Register the Menu*/ 
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ews_metas_add_admin_page');
function ews_metas_add_admin_page() { 
// Adds plugin page to menu
add_menu_page ('Effective Web Solutions Metas Descriptions', 'EWS Metas', 'manage_options', 'ews_meta_options_stephen_version', 'ews_meta_page_creation_stephen', get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/admin-ico-gray.png', 110 );
} 

/*Page Html Render*/
function ews_meta_page_creation_stephen() { ?>
<div>
<?php settings_errors(); ?>
<form method="post">
    <input id="meta" class="testing" type="text" name="2316" value="<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( 4189, '_metadescs', true ) ); ?>" />
    <?php submit_button();?>
</form>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready( function($){ 
jQuery(".toplevel_page_ews_meta_options_stephen_version form").submit(function() {
        var post_meta = jQuery("input.testing").val();
        var post_ID = jQuery("input.testing").attr("name");
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'https://dev.ewsproduction.com/dev6/ewstheme/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: {
                action: "update_meta_descriptions",
                post_id: post_ID,
                post_meta: post_meta,
            },
            success: function( data ) {
            //do something
            console.log('It worked!');
        }
    });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
<?php }

/*Update the meta using Ajax request */
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_meta_descriptions', 'update_meta_descriptions' );
function update_meta_descriptions() {
  global $wpdb;
  $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
  $meta = $_POST['post_meta'];
  $details = update_post_meta( $post_id, '_metadescs', $meta );
  echo 'Meta Updated';
  die();
}?>
```

Comment: Please describe what has been done and why.

Comment: @MaxYudin I have updated my answer as per your request.
Thank you for your comment. :)

Comment: @Stephen Burks Thank for your comment! Can you vote to the answer so another user-helpful it?

Comment: Your suggestions sounds reasonable, but I didn't test you code, so it's not my call to vote. Are you sure it works? Let's wait for OP reaction.

Comment: @MaxYudin - this did work well! Sorry for the late upvote - my profile is still new so I didn't realize I could up vote it!

I do have another follow up question that I am asking  if either of you have any interest in answering it would be greatly appreciated! I am just trying to figure out how to output and update the post meta if I have an array of data rather than just one value. Essentially, I can't get the DB to update when I am passing several values.